# Haskell - FFI and Pointers

Tags: haskell, ffi

I'm using the FFI in order to use a function in C that takes a struct and returns the same struct. The references I saw say I have to use pointers to these structures in order to be able to import it into Haskell. So, for example.

```
data Bar = Bar { a :: Int, b :: Int }
type BarPtr = Ptr (Bar)

foreign import ccall "static foo.h foo"
    f_foo :: BarPtr -> BarPtr
```

Now I have the problem that I have to be able to use the function. The [references](http://therning.org/magnus/archives/315) I saw had functions of type **BarPtr -> IO ()** and used **with**, which has signature **Storable a => a -> (Ptr a -> IO b) -> IO b**, which was ok, because they where calling the function inside main.

However, I would like to wrap this function in a library, getting a function of type **Bar -> Bar** without IO, is it possible to do without **unsafePerformIO**? What's the procedure?

Comment: If you want a pure function from something like `Ptr A -> IO ()`, then the correspond C function must be "almost pure" in the sense that the only effect it has is modifying the memory pointed to by is argument. If that is the case, you write a function of type `A -> A` by using Storable and `alloca` to create a pointer for C, then reading from that pointer and returning the value. This function is morally pure since it has no observable effect, so calling `unsafePerformIO` on it is perfectly fine (in fact this is the intended use of unsafePerformIO)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to remove `IO` from the type without using `unsafePerformIO`.  However, it is possible to get a function with the type you want in this case, with some caveats.  Specifically the C function "foo" cannot depend upon any global variables, thread-local state, or anything besides the single argument.  Also, calling `foo(bar)` should always provide the same result when `bar` is unchanged.

I expect that trying to import the C function

```
bar foo(bar input);
```

with this call

```
f_foo :: BarPtr -> BarPtr
```

will result in a compiler error due to the result type.  I think you may need to write a wrapper function (in C):

```
void wrap_foo(bar *barPtr) {
    bar outp = foo(*barPtr);
    *barPtr = outp;
}
```

and import it as

```
f_wrap_foo :: BarPtr -> IO ()
```

Finally, you would call this imported function with:

```
fooBar :: Bar -> Bar
fooBar bar = unsafePerformIO $ with bar $ \barPtr -> do
    f_wrap_foo barPtr
    peek barPtr
```

Comment: Tested and approved! Thank you!